# Ionic component in app.component.ts and pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

im struggeling with a custom component in ionic.

I have a menu in app.html and I use lazy-loading for the pages.

I try to implement the component into the menu in app.html and into some pages.

But I can only implement it into app.html or pages, not in both.

When I include the component only in app.module.ts the component works in app.html but if I include the component in my page template I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   'fa-icon' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

When I include the component in app.module.ts and in the page module I get the following error, because it's also included in app.module.ts:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type FaIconComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and BookingMasterPageModule! Please consider moving FaIconComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and BookingMasterPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FaIconComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and BookingMasterPageModule.

So my question is: How can I use the component in app.html and in my pages?

Comment: Well, second error gives you all the information you need. You need to create a module, let's call it `ComponentsModule` and declare and export all the components from this module. Then you can import `ComponentsModule` anywhere you want.

Comment: Great, that solved my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: I'll put my comment as an answer so other people can see the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, second error gives you all the information you need. You need to create a module, let's call it `ComponentsModule` and declare and export all the components from this module. Then you can import `ComponentsModule` anywhere you want

`components.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    exports: [MyComponent] // this line is important. If you forget it, other modules won't be able to use this component
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ComponentsModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`custom-page.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ComponentsModule]
})
export class CustomPageModule {}
```

Comment: Just a question about this approach, what if I have nearly 50 components in my ComponentsModule and I have imported this module in all my pages (nearly 100), will Angular bring all 50 components for every page in the memory  or it refers the already loaded components from the previous pages?