# Ionic 3, using multiple pages html for one component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, components, angular-routing

I'm using Ionic 3 and I have a question.

Is it possible for 2 pages of html to use the same 'component.ts'?

For example, if I have 2 pages:
1st page show all users,
2nd page show user's detail
and 1 component UserPage.

For Ionic 1, I can use one controller in multiple pages of html but in Ionic 3 I don't know if it's possible. If it possible, how can I call the page html on click? For example with the component we do like this:

> this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);

And for practice, is it better to use it this way or to use the normal way ( ionic g page XXX that generates all??)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this question that was answered before [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361059/ionic-component-in-app-component-ts-and-pages)

Comment: It's very bad coding practice though.. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you creating a separate page for details, i.e. `user-details`. In your list-page, let's call it `users`, you could do like this

```
this.navCtrl.push('user-details', { id: user.id });
```

This will send an ID-parameter to `user-details`, which you can get by doing following in your `user-details.ts`

```
userID: number;

constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
// ...
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.userID = this.navParams.get('id');
}
```

Of course, if you want to send a complete user-object, you just edit the object to be something like

```
{ user: user }
```

and access it at

```
this.navParams.get('user')
```

Using `this.navCtrl.setRoot()` for navigating is bad practise. Instead, you should use `this.navCtrl.push()` and `this.navCtrl().pop()`.